# Pushing new objects to an array not working

Tags: javascript, array-push

I'm making a game where I create objects randomly. So I create them on my game update, for now. The problem is that I can't push new objects to an array during runtime.

```
obstacles = [];    

Game.update = function() {
    this.player.move();
    obstacles.push(new Car());
    for (i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++) {
        obstacles[i].move();
    }
```

How do push the new objects to my array?

Comment: This should work. Have you put a `console.log` in your `update` function to verify that it is being called?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what happened. It actually works, but it is creating so many objects that the browse freezes.

I tried to put a Math.random() condition, but it still creates lots os objects.

Comment: Do you know how to make it don't create so many objects?

Comment: How do you use `Game.update`?

Comment: How often does Game.update get called, I think that is what he is asking.

Comment: You can limit the number by only adding if the array length is under. Eg `const MAX_CARS = 10;`  and then in the update function `if(obstacles.length < MAX_CARS) { obstacles.push(new Car())}` will limit to ten cars;

Comment: BTW you're referring to `this` in a method that isn't on the prototype, so it will refer to `window`.